# Finding max,min,avg and add new columns with results into a dataset in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I'm, newbie with Spark have this exercise to solve with the following
tables and i'm using spark 3.3.0

list of warehouse positions
(positionId, warehouse, product, eventTime)

| positionId | warehouse | product | eventTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | W-1 | P-1 | 1528463098 |
| 2 | W-1 | P-2 | 1528463100 |
| 3 | W-2 | P-3 | 1528463110 |
| 4 | W-2 | P-4 | 1528463111 |

list of amounts
(positionId, amount, eventTime)

| positionId | amount | eventTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.00 | 1528463098 |
| 1 | 10.20 | 1528463008 |
| 2 | 5.00 | 1528463100 |
| 3 | 4.90 | 1528463100 |
| 3 | 5.50 | 1528463111 |
| 3 | 5.00 | 1528463105 |
| 4 | 99.99 | 1528463111 |
| 4 | 99.57 | 1528463112 |

i need to find max, min, avg amounts for each warehouse and product and place the result in three new columns.

W-1, P-1, <max?(ex10.20)>, <min?(ex10.00)>, <avg?>

…..

W-2, P-4, <max?>, <min?>, <avg?>

so far i joined the two tables on positionId and dropped the columns that i think i won't need, such a positionId and eventTime for both.

`val all = amounts.join(whp, whp("positionId") === amounts("positionId"), "inner").drop(whp("eventTime")).drop(amounts("eventTime")).drop(whp("positionId")).drop(amounts("positionId")).show`

| amount | warehouse | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.00 | W-1 | P-1 |
| 10.20 | W-1 | P-1 |
| 5.00 | W-1 | P-2 |
| 4.90 | W-2 | P-3 |
| 5.50 | W-2 | P-3 |
| 5.00 | W-2 | P-3 |
| 99.99 | W-2 | P-4 |
| 99.57 | W-2 | P-4 |

What i tested so far is to get the max amount, but i don't know how to proceed further to get the min and the avg.

`val columnMax = all.groupBy("warehouse", "product").max("amount").show`

| warehouse | product | max(amount) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W-2 | P-3 | 5.50 |
| W-1 | P-2 | 5.00 |
| W-2 | P-4 | 99.99 |
| W-1 | P-1 | 10.20 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is correct , the only thing you need is to use [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg.html), when multiple columns are involved which allows you to pass multiple functions over columns

#### Data Preparation

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s1 = StringIO("""
positionId  warehouse   product eventTime
1   W-1 P-1 1528463098
2   W-1 P-2 1528463100
3   W-2 P-3 1528463110
4   W-2 P-4 1528463111
""")

s2 = StringIO("""
positionId  amount  eventTime
1   10.00   1528463098
1   10.20   1528463008
2   5.00    1528463100
3   4.90    1528463100
3   5.50    1528463111
3   5.00    1528463105
4   99.99   1528463111
4   99.57   1528463112
""")


df1 = pd.read_csv(s1,delimiter='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(s2,delimiter='\t')

warehouseDF = sql.createDataFrame(df1)
amountsDF = sql.createDataFrame(df2)
```

#### Aggregation

```
aggDF = warehouseDF.join(amountsDF
                        ,warehouseDF['positionId'] == amountsDF['positionId']
                    ).select(warehouseDF['warehouse']
                             ,warehouseDF['product']
                             ,amountsDF['amount']
                    ).groupBy(['warehouse','product'])\
                     .agg(*[
                                F.min(F.col('amount')).alias('min_amount')
                               ,F.max(F.col('amount')).alias('max_amount')
                               ,F.avg(F.col('amount')).alias('avg_amount')
                           ])

aggDF.show()

+---------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|warehouse|product|min_amount|max_amount|       avg_amount|
+---------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------+
|      W-2|    P-3|       4.9|       5.5|5.133333333333334|
|      W-1|    P-2|       5.0|       5.0|              5.0|
|      W-2|    P-4|     99.57|     99.99|            99.78|
|      W-1|    P-1|      10.0|      10.2|             10.1|
+---------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------+
```